# How to integrate TinyMCE in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I want to integrate TinyMCE in my Rails project. Where can I find a tutorial regarding this? I would also like to know whether there are any TinyMCE plugins.

Answer (score 0):

The `tiny_mce` gem is what you are searching for!

Comment: `This gem is being depreciated because I don’t have time to maintain it and the code base is in an inconsistent state! Seem following notes.`